# Ionic service is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

this current code returns this error :`TypeError: compteService.InsertCompte is not a function` because of `InsertCompte`

**service.js**

```
.factory('compteService', function($http, GetComptes) {


        var getComptes = function() {
            return $http.get(GetComptes.url);
        };

        return {
            getComptes: getComptes
        };
        var InsertCompte=function(user,compte){
            var strFinal = "[" + JSON.stringify(user) + "," +
                       JSON.stringify(account) + "]";
            return $http.post("http://localhost:26309/api/Compte/addUserV", strFinal)
            .then(function () {
                 $log.info("Insert Successful");
                return;
            });
        };
});
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('AjouterCompteCtrl', function($scope,compteService) {
 $scope.InsertAccount = function (user,account) {
            compteService.InsertCompte(user,account)
            .success(function() {
            console.log('success');

            }).error(function() {               
                console.log('error');
            });

        };    
  });
```

Comment: your factory doesn't `return` the `InsertCompte` function, it only returns `getComptes`.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of 2 issues in your code:

1. You are not returning method `InsertCompte` as part of the returned object from service

   ```
   return {
       getComptes: getComptes,
       InsertCompte: InsertCompte
   };
   ```
2. You are using a `function expression` as opposed to a `function declaration` to define the method `InsertCompte`. So even if you try returning the method `InsertCompte` as part of the service object mentioned in #1, your code won't work. This is a classic example of abuse of **revealing module pattern**. In case of angular factories always use the *revealing module pattern* along with *function declarations*.

   ```
   .factory('compteService', function($http, GetComptes) {
     return {
       getComptes: getComptes,
       InsertCompte: InsertCompte
     };


     function getComptes () {
       return $http.get(GetComptes.url);
     };

     function InsertCompte (user,compte){
       var strFinal = "[" + JSON.stringify(user) + "," +
                  JSON.stringify(account) + "]";
       return $http.post("http://localhost:26309/api/Compte/addUserV", strFinal)
       .then(function () {
            $log.info("Insert Successful");
           return;
       });
     };
   });
   ```

With the definition of factory in step 2, your code will work

Comment: thank you this resoved my problem , now am having another problem : POST http://localhost:26309/api/Compte/addUserV 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Here to help. Please accept/ upvote the answer as well :). For your other problem it's either an issue at server side or you are passing wrong value/ type if parameters causing a 500

Answer (score 0):

you can try rewriting your factory code following way:

```
angular.module("compteService",[])
.factory('compteService', function($http) {
var api_url ="http://localhost:26309/api/Compte/";
    return{
        getComptes:function(){
            return $http.get(api_url);
        },
        InsertCompte:function(user,compte){
              var strFinal = "[" + JSON.stringify(user) + "," +
                   JSON.stringify(account) + "]";
        return $http.post(api_url+"addUserV", strFinal)
        .then(function () {
             $log.info("Insert Successful");
            return;
        });
        }
    };
});
```